# Why can I not add to the authorised email senders list under app engine settings

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, sender

My domain name is hosted by app engine and configured under:

```
App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains
```

So why can I not add an email address to the authorised senders list:

```
App Engine -> Settings -> Email senders -> Authorised senders
```

When I try to add an email address like: `noreply@mydomain.com`, I get an error dialog telling me that the email address does not exist.

The email address does exist and works perfectly well.

Am I missing something? Where exactly should the email 'exist' for example. I've read and reread the documentation on this but it seems to me that this should work.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.163135996.-1187455873.1551224647&_gac=1.218399979.1553708153.CJ-ro-ztouECFXGxZQodj3kDZw#who_can_send_mail), and I get that you have your domain. However, I think you need to have your domain hosted on G Suite, not in App Engine, and that may be your problem.